# How to implement LAG operation or get previous row in NSFetchRequestResult in Core Data?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, core-data

I am writing a chat application with SwiftUI and I have a `LazyVStack` with a list of fetch results of message entities:

```swift
// other view properties

@FetchRequest private var messages: FetchedResults<Message>

init(contract: Contract) {
        _messages = FetchRequest<Message>(
            entity: Message.entity(),
            sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(key: "sent", ascending: true)],
            predicate: NSPredicate(format: "contract == %@", contract),
            animation: .easeIn
        )
}
```

```swift
// And in the view:

LazyVStack {
    ForEach(messages) { message in
        MessageView(message: message, viewWidth: reader.size.width)
    }
}
```

I want to display date badges, like in Telegram:

[image: Badges with Date]

The condition for showing a badge is when two neighboring rows of messages have different dates.

**The question is**: How to get the previous row in a `ForEach` loop over the fetch result?

Maybe fetch results can by enumerated somehow, but it is a dynamically mutated array... I need something like the LAG operation, so the code could be something like this:

```swift
// And in the view:

LazyVStack {
    ForEach(messages) { message in
        if message.previousRow.date != message.date {
            Text("\(message.date)")
        }
        MessageView(message: message, viewWidth: reader.size.width)
    }
}
```

EDIT (19.12.22):

I tried to convert the fetch results to array and the view became extremely slow. Even keyboard input was slow. I did it like this:

```swift
struct SomeView: View {
    @FetchRequest private var messages: FetchedResults<Message>

    var messagesArray: Array<Message> {
        Array(messages)
    }

    var body: some View: {
        ScrollView {
            LazyVStack {
                ForEach(Array(zip(messagesArray.indices, messagesArray)), id: \.0) { index, message in
                    if message.showMessage {
                        if let previousMessageSent = messagesArray[safe: index - 1]?.sent, let messageSent = message.sent, !isSameDay(date1: previousMessageSent, date2: messageSent) {
                            Text(messageSent, formatter: DateFormatter.ddMMyyyy)
                        }
                        MessageView(viewWidth: reader.size.width, message: message)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It doesn't work : ( Maybe there are other options?

Comment: Why not try to use enumerated as you mentioned, if the `messages` property is modified the view will be regenerated using a new enumeration

Comment: @Joakim I tried to convert the fetch results to array and the view became extremely slow. Even keyboard input was slow. I edited my question and described my method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone was interested i solved it with relations in *Messages* model.

First i created `previousMessage` *one to one* relationship in *Messages*.

Then on saving Messages I call a function that connects objects to each other:

```swift
func markNextAndPreviousMessages(for contract: Contract, for context: NSManagedObjectContext) throws {
    let fetchRequest = Message.fetchRequest()
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "contract = %@", contract)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = __messagesSortDescriptors
    let results = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
    let resultsArray = Array(results)
    for (index, message) in resultsArray.enumerated() {
        message.previousMessage = resultsArray[safe: index - 1]
    }
}
```

And finally in the View:

```swift
LazyVStack {
    ForEach(messages) { message in
        if let messageSent = message.sent, 
           let previousMessageSent = message.previousMessage?.sent, 
           !previousMessageSent.isInSameDay(as: messageSent) {
            MessageTimeDividerView(date: messageSent)
        }
        MessageView(message: message)
    }
}
```

This solution worked for me. If you know something better, I'll be happy to see.